# Filemaker: Copying records from one table to another

Tags: copy, filemaker

I have a database with tables ( case, knowledgebase)

Case table has fields linked to a specific customer

Knowledgebase table is separate and doesn't care about customer.

I want to have the user click a button occasionally to copy their solution (from Case Table) to a new record in knowledgebase table  (just two fields, desc, solution)

I just don't know the steps to 'copy'

Comment: Not sure what application and DB are you using and if you want to it at the application level or database level - Can you please clarify that in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly:

```
Set Variable [$desc; Value:  Case::desc]
Set Variable [$solution; Value:  Case::solution]
Go to Layout [ Knowledgebase ]
New Record/Request
Set Field [Knowledgebase::desc; $desc]
Set Field [Knowledgebase::solution; $solution]
Commit Records []
```

Comment: I couldn't understand the question, until I read your answer.